# How to use VNC Viewer to installing Oracle 12c to a database without X?

Tags: linux, database, oracle, vnc, vnc-viewer

I have installed Oracle Linux 6.8 server, and I must to install an Oracle 12c to it, without X. I should use VNC Viewer, witch I installed, and it's working.

My problem is, when I run ./runInstaller, its says:"Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set."

How to solve this problem using VNC, and how to set DISPLAY variable (where is it, and how to set is correctly)?

Answer (score 0):

The DISPLAY variable is intended for the X server rather than VNC.  This may resolve the issue for you.

Install Cygwin if you are using a Windows machine at http://cygwin.com/ and configure it with the x server.  If you are on an OS X machine install Xquartz.

Connect to the machine with ssh in the following manner.

ssh -X user@hostname

The -X option for ssh automatically sets the DISPLAY variable for you.  When you run ./runinstaller it will display the installations screen on your local workstation if you have X configured correctly there.

Here's a blog article I wrote for OTN that contains more information and may be of assistance for you.

https://blogs.oracle.com/OTNGarage/entry/more_tips_for_remote_access1